# Programmatically create users in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, roles, rbac, k8s-serviceaccount, k8s-rolebinding

I am looking for a way to create/retrieve/update/delete a user in Kubernetes, such that I can allow him certain stuff via RoleBindings.

Everything I have found is more or less manual work on the master node. However, I imagine a service deployed in Kubernetes I could call via an API to do the magic for me without doing any manual work. Is such a thing available?

Answer (score 1):

From https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#users-in-kubernetes

> All Kubernetes clusters have two categories of users: service accounts
> managed by Kubernetes, and normal users.
>
> Kubernetes does not have objects which represent
> normal user accounts. Normal users cannot be added to a cluster
> through an API call.
>
> Even though a normal user cannot be added via an API call, any user
> that presents a valid certificate signed by the cluster's certificate
> authority (CA) is considered authenticated.

So there is no API call to create normal user. However you can create service accounts that can have RoleBindings [bound](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-binding-examples) to them.

Another possibility is to create TLS certificate, sign it with Kubernetes cluster CA (using [CSR](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/)s) and use it as a "normal user".